# Connect OLED display to dev board

Tags: arduino, esp8266, display, oled

I want to use a small OLED display for a project. I need a color display as small as possible and I found these models that would be good for my application:

- [MDT0096AIH-SPI](https://de.farnell.com/midas/mdt0096aih-spi/lcd-tft-anzeige-0-96-80-x-160p/dp/3618217?pf_custSiteRedirect=true)
- [MDT0096AISC-SPI](https://de.farnell.com/en-DE/midas/mdt0096aisc-spi/lcd-tft-module-spi-80x160p-rgb/dp/3759045?pf_custSiteRedirect=true)

I will use an Arduino 1010 WiFi or ESP8266 as development board.
It's the first time I use such a display and I don't know how to connect it.

1. Is an additional display driver needed? If so, which model?
2. On the software side, what library should be used to make it work?

Comment: Those devices have SPI interfaces so connect them to the SPI interface on your development board. Recommendations for products such as libraries are off-topic here but have a good look through the forums for the board to see what other people use, if there even any available.

Comment: As it was suggested use a SPI interface. The driver is the ST7735S so look for code/libraries that are for this driver. Otherwise choose an OLED with a  driver that is more commonly available (but older) such as an SSD1306 etc. and then find the code for this.... In other words pick an OLED with code available for the most commonly used driver IC and then find the OLED size and interface that is available and suits your application.

Comment: Thank you all for help!